# Help with MKV to MP4 Remux script

Tags: bash, scripts, ffmpeg, find, mp4

Overview:

I'm trying to remux my mostly MKV library to MP4. I have a script that has gone through and extracted subtitles from the video files.

I have another script that will remux any .mkv files in a given folder. What I need is for the script to **only** remux folders where it detects that there are .srt files.

All the .srt files end with ***.eng.srt

Here's my current remux script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
IFS=$'\n' 
clear 
for filename in *.mkv 
do 
echo "$filename" 
newfilename="${filename%.mkv}.mp4" 
echo "${newfilename}" 
ffmpeg -fix_sub_duration -i $filename -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text $newfilename 
done
```

Thanks! any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

clear
for filename in *.mkv 
do 
    ## Exit if there are no srt files
    [ ! -e *.srt ] && echo "No .srt files found, exiting" && exit
    echo "$filename" 
    newfilename="${filename%.mkv}.mp4" 
    echo "${newfilename}" 
    ffmpeg -fix_sub_duration -i "$filename" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text "$newfilename" 
done
```

I removed the `IFS='\n'` since it's not doing anything useful there, your `for` loop is quite safe even with names containing whitespace as long as you quote your variables.

The `[ -e foo ]` tests for the existence of `foo`. Conversely, `[ ! -e foo ]` is true if there is no `foo`. In this case, `foo` is a glob (`*.srt`) so the test will be false if any matching files are found. In the script above, the `&&` mean that if no `srt` files are found, the error message will be printed and the script will exit.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, seems to be working, any suggestions on adding the ability to delete the .mkv once the mp4 has been remuxed?

Comment: @PatWoodward glad it works. As for removing the mkv, just add `&& rm "$filename"` to the end of the `ffmpeg` line.